# Write to a specified set of columns in an existing xlsx file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file and I want to add a dataframe to it. I have to put the data in specific columns and these columns are at the start of the file. Since, I have to do this process each day, I also have to clear those columns first. I need to put data from columns A to G and then the excel file has a few formulae that I want to apply in the rest of the columns from H onwards. I only want to write the data to the first A to G columns and have the data in H column onwards intact. Is there a way to write the data only in few excel columns and not the others.

I am using `openpyxl` for it but running into a few issues. The major issue is that instead of adding the data to columns A to G, it gets overwritten each time in column H onwards as well. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, there is very little detail and you state " I also have to clear those columns first" and then "data gets overwritten each time", if you are clearing the columns how can it matter if the data is overwritten? Likely you can do what you want using ExcelWriter with Openpyxl as the Engine and append data however really unclear what your starting with and wanting to end with. Where is the MRE of the code you are using?

Comment: I have added more explanation. Let me know if you understand that now? I want to clear columns from A to G and write data in it again but instead columns from A to Z get overwrriten and I don't want that. I didn't add the code as it's not going to add more context to the problem. Let me know if this was more clear to you?

Answer (score 0):

To write a dataframe to an existing worksheet without affecting any existing data on the sheet or indeed the whole workbook you can use an ExcelWriter in append mode.

The writer is enabled in 'append' mode; `mode=a` which requires the engine to be Openpyxl.
To leave existing data in the sheet untouched 'if_sheet_exists' is set to 'overlay'. In this case data is overwritten only if it exists in the cells 'to_excel' writes to.

In the example code below foo.xlsx and Sheet1 exist with data in Columns H onwards on Sheet1. A dataframe with 7 columns is written to Sheet1 in Columns A to G.

This code will write the data from cell A1 to Column G (G7)
Only data in this range is overwritten if any exists.

```
import pandas as pd

### Test dataframe with test data
data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Musk melon', 'grapes'],
                            'Weight': [20, 30, 15, 10, 50, 40],
                            'Quantity': [4, 12, 31, 1, 31, 63],
                            'Dates': ['2020', '2019', '2023', '2022', '2023', '2019'],
                            'Names': ['Pete', 'Jordan', 'Gustaf', 'Sophie', 'Sally', 'Simone'],
                            'Age': [22, 21, 19, 19, 29, 21],
                            'Utensil': ['knife', 'fork', 'spoon', 'plate', 'cup', 'saucer']
                            })

### Create a context manager for the writer and set the operation states 
with pd.ExcelWriter("foo.xlsx", 
                    mode="a",  # Mode a for 'append'
                    engine="openpyxl",  # Must be openpyxl for appending
                    if_sheet_exists='overlay'  # Only overwrite data if its in the dataframe range
                   ) as writer:
    ### Write data to the sheet
    data_frame.to_excel(writer,
                         sheet_name="Sheet1",  # Name of Sheet to write to
                         # startrow=0,  # Row to start writing dataframe write, note 0 is row 1 and is the default
                         # startcol=0,  # Column to start writing dataframe, also starts at 0 which is the default
                         # header=True,  # Include dataframe Header, default is True
                         index=False  # Write the dataframe without the index column
                         )
```